# sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found when creating a new google sheet with python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have created a new google sheet using google api. I was able to create it if I have one file for all the below tasks:
Create credential and create an instance of sheets
Create a new sheet with a title
Add permissions to the sheet so that I can access it

Below code runs successfully :

```
## Define scopes and service account file - these are like ID and password for google api
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'

## Authorizing to connect with google api scopes(these scopes should be enabled in google api)
creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

spreadsheet_id = Null
spreadsheet = {
    'properties': {
        'title': 'Test'
    }
}
# connecting to google sheets api
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials = creds)
        
# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

# Create spreadsheet with title
create_response = sheet.create(body = spreadsheet, fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
spreadsheet_id = create_response.get('spreadsheetId')

# Add permissions to account/emails
permits = [{'role': 'writer', 'type':'user', 'emailAddress': 'itika.sharma10@gmail.com'}]

# connecting to google drive api
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials = creds)

for permit in permits:
        res = drive.permissions().create(fileId = spreadsheet_id, body = permit, fields="id").execute()
```

Now, I wanted to have separate files and functions for all these tasks like below:
Credentials.py - to create sheet instance
Permissions.py - to add permissions
Create.py - to create a new sheet and I am calling the other two files from this file

```
SCOPES = [['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'], ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']]

spreadsheet_id = Null 
spreadsheet = {
    'properties': {
        'title': 'Test'
    }
}

def create_sheet(spreadsheet):
        # connecting to google sheets api
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials = creds)
        
        # Call the Sheets API
        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    
        # Create spreadsheet with title
        create_response = sheet.create(body = spreadsheet, fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
        spreadsheet_id = create_response.get('spreadsheetId')

        return(spreadsheet_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    creds = credentials.create_creds(SCOPES)
    spreadsheet_id = create_sheet(spreadsheet)
    permissions.add_permissions(spreadsheet_id, SCOPES)
```

But I get below error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
  File "C:\Users\itika\Desktop\Python\web\Untitled Folder\create.py", line 25, in create_sheet
    create_response = sheet.create(body = spreadsheet, fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
  File "C:\Users\itika\Desktop\Python\web\Untitled Folder\create.py", line 32, in <module>
    spreadsheet_id = create_sheet(spreadsheet)
```

I checked the type of creds, spreadsheet and sheet for both the codes and compared them. They are identical.

Can someone help to resolve this error.

Comment: What is *Null*?

Comment: I added it to initiate this variable with Null. I checked with 0 as well, I got the same error.

Comment: I was asking because it's not a valid *Python* identifier. It's probably some *Google Sheets* constant.

Comment: You should definitely read about [NoneType](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp) as you can't use `Null` in python.

Comment: Also your Scopes list in the second example is a list of 1-element lists rather than a list of strings which might be the source of your error

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou:  Yes, that worked. I updated the list of lists to a list of strings and it fixed the issue.
Thank you!